# Best way to define 'mainEntityOfPage' in Microdata?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

I know at least 2 ways to define `mainEntityOfPage`:

```html
<div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/article-1" />
</div>
```

and

```html
<div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="Mycontent" itemscope itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://example.com/article-1"/>
</div>
```

Both ways are succesfully validated. The questions are:

1. Which way is more optimal/universal/recognizible for search engines?
2. If I markup them both simultaneously is it ok? (Validator gives no errors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I described the [different ways how `mainEntityOfPage` can be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117597/1591669) in an answer on Stack Overflow.

The difference between your two examples is that the second one creates an item (with the type `WebPage`), while the first one just points to another page (which might or might not define a type).

From the perspective of Schema.org, both ways are fine. The [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) property expects a `URL` (= your first example) or a `CreativeWork` (= your second example) as value.

In my opinion, the second example is not very elegant. The `content` attribute of the `meta` element will be ignored (because of the `itemscope`), but HTML5+Microdata requires it to be there. Pro: it adds (on the source page) the information that the URL represents a web page; in theory, consumers would not have to visit the URL to learn what it represents (= a `WebPage`). However, that is probably the default assumption in that context anyway.

It shouldn’t matter which way you choose. FWIW, [Google’s Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) seems to be fine with both.